# Spring-Data JPA persisting unreferenced entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    // ... //

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Lob
    private BitSet bitSet;
    // ... //

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<A> as;
}
```

In my code, I have the following sequence that creates an A and assigns a new B, and later in the code when a service class goes to save the A, the service checks whether an equivalent B already exists in the database, and if so replaces A's B with the one found in the database. A little convoluted I know, but we didn't want the code that creates A's to know about the database, and the actual code is, of course, more complicated.

```
// Initialization code happens in one part
A a = new A();
a.setB( new B() );  // This new B get's saved even if it is replaced later!

// Later a service is used to save the new A
B repoB = bRepository.findOneByBitSet( a.getB().getBitSet() );
if (repoB != null) {
    a.setB(repoB);  // Replace the temporary B
} // Otherwise we will keep the original B.
aRepository.save(a);
```

Ok, so now here's the problem. A's original B is saved to the database, even though this new B is not referenced by any object. Why would Spring-Data save this unreferenced B object.

If I were working directly with Hibernate I could have used an evict() on the unwanted B like so, but Spring-Data does not expose such a call:

```
// Later a service is used to save the new A
B repoB = bRepository.findOneByBitSet( a.getB().getBitSet() );
if (repoB != null) {
    B unwantedB = a.getB();
    a.setB(repoB);  // Replace the unwanted B
    hibernate.evict(unwantedB);
} // Otherwise we will keep the original B.
aRepository.save(a);
```

A more direct example of the scenario would be:

```
A a = new A();
B unwantedB = new B();
a.setB(unwantedB);
B b = newB();
a.setB(b);
repository.save(a);
```

Object "a" should be persisted with a reference to object "b", but I would think object "unwantedB" would not be persisted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would Spring-Data save this unreferenced B object.?

Because you are using `cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })` on you collection association

> If I were working directly with Hibernate I could have used an evict()
>   on the unwanted B like so, but Spring-Data does not expose such a call

That is correct , so consider to set to null the field for B in the relationship. It means remove reference from A to B

`a.setB( new B() );`  to `a.setB(null);`   before persist if not entity will be added an persist time

If you dont wanto to store new entities in B remove cascade options.

Comment: Yes the cascade on the collection is there to save the associated B but the later a.setB( repoB ) should remove the reference to the original B associated in the a.setB ( new B() ) line. It's the object created by the newB() that I wouldn't have expected to be saved.

Comment: NOT remove because Cascade.REMOVE is not present, consider add it

Comment: According to [JPA / Hibernate Cascade.Remove use case for \@ManyToOne](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620242/jpa-hibernate-cascade-remove-use-case-for-manytoone) and JPA 2.0 specifications is that CascadeType.REMOVE is only applicable to \@OneToOne and \@OneToMany.